# Google Application Default Credential not working in the cloud

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm trying to use Application Default Credentials in a Java Google App Engine app. When running locally, the credentials work fine and the following example code logs my service account ID and access token as expected.

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

  //Literally one line of code for GAE credentials
  GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();

  LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Service Account Id: {0}", credential.getServiceAccountId());
  LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Access Token: {0}", credential.getAccessToken()); 
}
```

However, when running this exact code deployed in the cloud the logs are as follows:

```
16:03:58.585 com.test.servlet.MyServlet doGet: Service Account Id: null
16:03:58.681 com.test.servlet.MyServlet doGet: Access Token: null
```

Is there any reason why the Application Default Credentials would be null in the cloud? Is there some configuration that I'm missing? According to the [Authentication Docs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication) this should just work automatically:

> If you need to run your code on Google App Engine, you should use Application Default Credentials (ADC). Client libraries using ADC automatically obtain the built-in service account credentials from App Engine at runtime.

Comment: I'm also seeing this still.  Were you able to track this down?

Comment: I never managed to solve this. In the end, I just used AuthCredentials.createForJson() with my service account key file instead.

Comment: Had this issue too, but you are currently unable to get that info from the default appengine credentials. If you have to impersonate someone, you have to add the .json in your resources and parse it by hand.